# Python connection to OneDrive - Unauthorized Access

Tags: python, authentication, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

Here's my problem:
I have a 365 Family OneDrive subscription with 3 members, my account being the admin.
I am trying to build a python application to read/extract the content of the files I have on this onedrive space based on specific criterias. I want to build it as a command line application, running locally on my PC. I am aware some tools may exist for this but I'd like to code my own solution.

After going through tons of different documentation, I ended up doing the following

- Registered my application on the Azure portal
- Granted some permission on the Microsoft Graph API (User.read, Files.Read and Files.ReadAll)
- Created a secret
- Grabbed the sample code provided by Microsoft
- Replaces some variables with my Client_Id and Secret
- Ran the code

The code returns an access token but the authorization requests fails with *401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials*.

Here's the Python code I'm using.

```
import msal

config = {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers",
    "client_id": "<my client ID>",
    "scope": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],
    "secret": "<My secret stuff>",
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
}
# Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    client_credential=config["secret"],
)

result = None

result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=None)

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, ).json()
    print("Graph API call result: ")
    print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
```

According to the error message, I'm obviously missing something in the authorization process but can't tell what. I'm not even sure about the Authority and Endpoints I should use. My account being a personal one, I have no tenant.
Do I need to set-up / configure some URI somewhere?

Any help would be welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your client app you need to store the token that you are getting from the MSAL. and then send the token with an authorized request.

For OneDrive, download the OneDrive for [python](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python#onedrive-for-business). You can see the different option for [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types).

The reason you are getting an access token, ID token, and a refresh token is because of the flow you're using. My suggestion is to review the flows for a better understanding of how the authentication process works and what will be returned accordingly. You can use this MSAL library for [python](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki).